# How hard is it to run forced hot air and baseboard zones off one Trane furnace?

Tags: hvac, heating, baseboard

I have a trane forced hot air HVAC that heats my house. I have a small extension that is cold.  How much work is involved to connect a baseboard zone to the existing forces hot air furnace?  Is it relatively easy or just not possible, or in between?
(Trane model 4TXCD061BC3HCAA)

Answer (score 1):

You could have an HVAC company install a zone system to control the heating and A/C in both areas. Or you could add a separate system just for that room.

Comment: OK, you are saying it is possible.  Is it a big deal?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC it's impossible to say from where we sit and look at this.   Typically "baseboard" heat is not powered from a forced air furnace.   There is no way to tell you what is best for your situation.   I suspect it is more economical for you to install a separate heater for this area, likely an electric baseboard heater.  Call local heating professional s and ask them to review the possibilities.